# Create input name from array like #parent

Tags: forms

I'm just wondering if there is a Drupal way / helper function to build input[name] string from array.

So I have an array '#parents' = ["info","variation-555-1","example","example"];

and I want the string to go in the input [name=`info[variation-555-1][example][example]`]

Answer (score 0):

I found the same code in many places by searching `implode(']['` which seems to be way drupal does it, so the answer is `no`, there is no helper function, but it's only a few lines.

```
$selector = $root = array_shift($parents);
if ($parents) {
    $selector = $root . '[' . implode('][', $parents) . ']';
}
```